# Flutter, ScaleTransition vs Transform.scale

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

So there are 2 types in explicit animations right?

Aren't ScaleTransition and Transform.scale both explicit animations?

Why do you need two methods?

Comment: `Transform.scale` is a static widget while `ScaleTransition` is a dynamic one driven by an animation (`Animation<double> scale`) - for example you can pass directly `AnimationController`

Comment: hi pskink! which one is more used in practice in complex cases??

Comment: after grepping the flutter source code it seems that `ScaleTransition` is used two times often

Comment: @PaemKacit To understand what fits your requirement, see this article
https://medium.com/flutter/how-to-choose-which-flutter-animation-widget-is-right-for-you-79ecfb7e72b5

Comment: @PaemKacit the above article is based on this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnARLByOtKA

Comment: btw, this is how `ScaleTransition` is implemented: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c19845a8c3/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/transitions.dart#L287 - it extends `AnimatedWidget` and uses `Transform.scale` inside `build()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Transform.scale` is a static scaling widget, that cannot perform animation itself, and should be wrapped inside a `TweenAnimationBuilder`. The animation cannot be controlled once completed.

`ScaleTransition` takes `Animation` as a value of its `scale` parameter which is controlled by `AnimationController` hence it's an explicit animation.

Comment: so u mean Transform.scale is implicit animation??

Comment: @PaemKacit no `Transform.scale` is not an animation at all - it is just a static widget and if you want to "animate" it you should use it inside `AnimatedBuilder` / `ValueListenableBuilder` / `AnimatedWidget` for example